# Use gulp imagemin optimizers in combination with gulp-load-plugins

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I'm using Gulp-load-plugins (https://github.com/jackfranklin/gulp-load-plugins) to require all my plugins automatically.

As in

```
// Load Gulp plugins
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
```

Now to use imagemin, I have the following setup

```
// Imagemin
.pipe(plugins.imagemin({
    optimizationLevel: 3,
    progressive: true,
    svgoPlugins: [{
        removeViewBox: false
    }],
    interlaced: true,
    use: [plugins.svgo()]
}))
```

But I get the error "TypeError: Object # has no method 'svgo'".
In the documentation of imagemin, they require the optimisers separately. 
Is this possible in combination with the grunt-load-plugins module? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should install [**imagemin-svgo**](https://github.com/kevva/imagemin-svgo) plugin to get this work, because it is not included by default to `gulp-imagemin` like precised at the bottom line of the [README](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/blob/master/readme.md).

Install it using `npm`:

```
npm install --save imagemin-svgo
```

And `require` it in your `gulpfile` since the `gulp-load-plugins` follow the `gulp-*` pattern and will not load it. And call it in the `use options` like you did before.

Comment: This indeed works. But it's strange, cause if you download gulp-imagemin, imagemin-svgo is also downloaded in the node_modules folder of gulp-imagemin. Strange that you need to download it separately also...

Comment: That's only if you want to use it in your `gulpfile`, because you can't access the dependencies of one of your modules, expect if you do something like `require('./node_modules/gulp-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-svgo');` which is a little tricky